# When to use DATE_TRUNC() vs. DATE_PART()?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do not know when to use `DATE_TRUNC` and `DATE_PART()` in a query.

I have not really tried much, just some web searches that I do not fully grasp but I just started learning SQL (Postgres).

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Answer (score 3):

They both do very different things. One truncates a date to the precision specified (kind of like rounding, in a way) and the other just returns a particular part of a datetime.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

**date_part()**:

> The date_part function is modeled on the traditional Ingres equivalent
> to the SQL-standard function extract:

```
date_part('field', source)
```

> Note that here the field parameter needs to be a string value, not a
> name. The valid field names for date_part are the same as for [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT).
> For historical reasons, the date_part function returns values of type
> double precision. This can result in a loss of precision in certain
> uses. Using extract is recommended instead.

```
SELECT date_part('day', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 16

SELECT date_part('hour', INTERVAL '4 hours 3 minutes');
Result: 4
```

**date_trunct()**:

> The function date_trunc is conceptually similar to the trunc function
> for numbers.
>
> date_trunc(field, source [, time_zone ]) source is a value expression
> of type timestamp, timestamp with time zone, or interval. (Values of
> type date and time are cast automatically to timestamp or interval,
> respectively.) field selects to which precision to truncate the input
> value. The return value is likewise of type timestamp, timestamp with
> time zone, or interval, and it has all fields that are less
> significant than the selected one set to zero (or one, for day and
> month).

...

> Examples (assuming the local time zone is America/New_York):

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-02-16 20:00:00

SELECT date_trunc('year', TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40');
Result: 2001-01-01 00:00:00

SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00');
Result: 2001-02-16 00:00:00-05

SELECT date_trunc('day', TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2001-02-16 20:38:40+00', 'Australia/Sydney');
Result: 2001-02-16 08:00:00-05

SELECT date_trunc('hour', INTERVAL '3 days 02:47:33');
Result: 3 days 02:00:00
```